# how to Stop HazelCast Cluster in enterprise version

Tags: hazelcast

Can I stop the Hazelcast cluster through REST API instead of using UI in the enterprise version?
what is the command that I can use?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the following REST Endpoint: `/hazelcast/rest/management/cluster/clusterShutdown`.

Note that you need to have the REST Endpoint Group `CLUSTER_WRITE` enabled.

Read more at [Hazelcast Reference Manual: Using the REST Endpoint Groups](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#using-the-rest-endpoint-groups).